# Use a C# file in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I heard that it's possible to import a c# file and use it's functions in a vb.net application? I have a C# file with a lot of functions, that I want to use, however, I don't want to convert it to vb.net (would take time). Is it possible? Thanks. HOw?

Comment: Is it a DLL (Class Library)?  Then simply add it as a reference to your project and add the `Imports xxx` statement to your code.

Comment: When you compile a class it is transformed into MSIL (Microsoft Intermediate Language). Whether it's C# or VB.NET they are identical at this stage.

Answer (score 2):

Compile it, and reference the DLL.

Comment: See "Project-to-Project References": [Managing Project References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew(v=vs.110).aspx)